# Play video in javascript pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, wmv

We have an anchor tag referred to a video as follows:

```
<p><a class="some_class" href="javascript:PlayVideo('path/video.wmv')">Learn</a></p>
```

The javascript method "PlayVideo" is used to play the video in a pop-up as follows. Script is as follows:

```
function PlayVideo(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(url, "Learn", "width=320,height=320,status=yes");
    popupWindow.moveTo(80, 80);
}
```

The problem is that on clicking the "href" link, the video gets downloaded instead of playing in the pop-up. Our expected behavior is to view the video in the pop-up itself instead of downloading. I'm a newbie in javascript, so please help me in achieving the purpose.

Comment: you need to play `video` not just pass the link .

Comment: @TusharGupta, Ok, thanks. Can you please let me know a better and common used approach to play the video. Please note that the video format used is ".wmv".

Comment: A general tip - never use `javascript:` URLs. Give the element an ID or something an in your JavaScript, call 'thatElement.addEventListener("click", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); /* Do play video stuff here. */}, false)`.

Comment: you can use HTML5 video tag and http://www.videojs.com/ . https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/setup.md

Comment: WMV means you must have a Window Media Player plugin in a page. You cannot just load the WMV as a URL. Research it first and if you cannot find anything, ask here.

Comment: @TusharGupta are you sure? I dont believe the video tag supports wmv

Comment: @TusharGupta - `<video>` does not support WMV. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772959(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I researched and got to know that HTML 5 video tag, does not support videos of .wmv format.

Comment: @andrew you need to convert to `mp4` and `webm` to it work on all browsers .

Comment: @user3220129 - right, so research the way to embed the Window Media Player plugin.

Comment: Or research encoding your video into a different file type

Comment: @andrew this might help you converting http://easyhtml5video.com/

Comment: @andrew or you can simply use YouTube link in `<iframe>` .

Comment: @TusharGupta I know how to convert, my point is the op wishes to use a wmv file, I agree with you, wmv is not a good format to use, but your comment does not answer the ops question

Comment: @andrew That's why it is posted as comment not as answer .